# unexplained linker error

Tags: c++, linker

I have the following files on my computer.

```
/lib64/libm.so.6
/usr/lib64/libm.so
```

but when I link with the following, I get errors

```
$ g++ -L/usr/lib64 -O3 -static -Wall -Wno-char-subscripts -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -IMSToolkit/include Comet.o Threading.o CometSearch.o CometPreprocess.o CometPostAnalysis.o CometMassSpecUtils.o CometWriteOut.o CometWriteSqt.o CometWritePepXML.o -LMSToolkit -lmstoolkitlite -o comet.exe
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lm
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
$
```

Does anyone knows why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes I do. You are trying to link a static exe with no shared libraries - the libraries you have are shared because of the `.so` extension - you need to install libm.a

Either remove the `-static` option or install the `.a` versions of the library